# ORA-00904: invalid identifier and ORA-02256: number of referencing columns must match referenced columns (oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle

hi guys im sorry i'm real new to sql and databases and I'm trying to create these 3 tables but its not letting me thanks to these two types of errors and i'm looking at them but not quite understanding how to fix them, I think i'm having trouble understanding and solidifying the syntax of creating foreign keys and primary keys from other tables, here is the erorrs, followed by the create table statements:

```
Table created.

1 row created.

Constraint DepartmentFK FOREIGN KEY(DepartmentName)
                                    *
ERROR at line 12: 
ORA-00904: "DEPARTMENTNAME": invalid identifier 
Constraint EmployeePK   PRIMARY KEY(EmployeeNumber),
                                    *
ERROR at line 9: 
ORA-00904: "EMPLOYEENUMBER": invalid identifier 
)
*
ERROR at line 11: 
ORA-02256: number of referencing columns must match referenced columns
```

I'm pretty much trying to answer these questions if it helps:

```
7.5 Write a CREATE TABLE statement for the EMPLOYEE table. Email is required and is 
an alternate key, and the default value of Department is Human Resources. Cascade
updates but not deletions from DEPARTMENT to EMPLOYEE.

7.6 Write a CREATE TABLE statement for PROJECT table. The default value for MaxHours is 100.
 Cascade updates but not deletions from DEPARTMENT to EMPLOYEE. 

7.7 Write a CREATE TABLE statement for the ASSIGNMENT table. Cascade only deletions from
PROJECT to ASSIGNMENT; do not cascade either deletions or updates from EMPLOYEE to 
ASSIGNMENT.

7.8 Modify your answer to Review Question 7.7 to include the constraint that StartDate
 be prior to EndDate.
```

and heres my code:

```
CREATE TABLE DEPARTMENT (
DepartmentName  char(35) NOT NULL,
BudgetCode      char(30) NOT NULL,
OfficeNumber    char(15) NOT NULL,
Phone           char(12) NOT NULL,

Constraint DepartmentPK PRIMARY KEY(DepartmentName)

);

INSERT INTO DEPARTMENT VALUES (
    'Administration', 'BC-100-10', 'BLDG01-300', '360-285-8100');

CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE (
EmployeeNumber  int         NOT NULL,
FirstName       char(25)    NOT NULL,
LastName        char(25)    NOT NULL,
Department      char(35)    DEFAULT 'Human Resources' NOT NULL,
Phone           char(12)    NULL,
Email           char(30)    NOT NULL,


Constraint EmployeePK   PRIMARY KEY(EmployeeNumber),
Constraint EmployeeAK1 UNIQUE(Email),
Constraint DepartmentFK FOREIGN KEY(DepartmentName)
    references DEPARTMENT(DepartmentName)
--ON UPDATE CASCADE 
-- ON DELETE no ACTION 

);

CREATE TABLE PROJECT (
ProjectID   int         NOT NULL,
Name        char(30)    NOT NULL,
Department1 char(15)    NOT NULL,
MaxHours    int         DEFAULT 100 NOT NULL,
StartDate   DATE        NULL,
EndDate     DATE        NULL,

Constraint EmployeePK   PRIMARY KEY(EmployeeNumber),
constraint DepartmentFK FOREIGN KEY(DepartmentName)
    references DEPARTMENT(DepartmentName)
-- ON UPDATE CASCADE 
-- ON DELETE no ACTION 
);

CREATE TABLE Assignment(
ProjectID       Number       NOT NULL,
EmployeeNumber  Number      NOT NULL,
HoursWorked     Number      NULL,

Constraint  datecheck check (Assignment.StartDate < Assignment.EndDate),
Constraint ProjectIDEmpNumPK    PRIMARY KEY(ProjectID, EmployeeNumber),
constraint ProjectIDEmpNumFK FOREIGN KEY(ProjectID, DepartmentName)
    references EMPLOYEE(DepartmentName)
--ON DELETE CASCADE 
);
```

i tried looking up these errors and i was just following the examples in my book I am confused :(

I finally got the tables to work. it was important to understand how to do a proper foreign key declaration, each having to be unique in each child table.

```
CREATE TABLE DEPARTMENT (
DepartmentName  char(35) NOT NULL,
BudgetCode      char(30) NOT NULL,
OfficeNumber    char(15) NOT NULL,
Phone           char(12) NOT NULL,

Constraint DepartmentPK PRIMARY KEY(DepartmentName)

);

INSERT INTO DEPARTMENT VALUES (
    'Administration', 'BC-100-10', 'BLDG01-300', '360-285-8100');

CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE (
EmployeeNumber  int         NOT NULL,
FirstName       char(25)    NOT NULL,
LastName        char(25)    NOT NULL,
Department      char(35)    DEFAULT 'Human Resources' NOT NULL,
Phone           char(12)    NULL,
Email           char(30)    NOT NULL,
DepartmentName_FK char(35) NOT NULL,

Constraint EmployeePK   PRIMARY KEY(EmployeeNumber),
Constraint EmployeeAK1 UNIQUE(Email),
Constraint DepartmentFK FOREIGN KEY (DepartmentName_FK)
    references DEPARTMENT(DepartmentName)
--ON UPDATE CASCADE 
--ON DELETE no ACTION 

);

CREATE TABLE PROJECT (
ProjectID   int         NOT NULL,
Name        char(30)    NOT NULL,
Department1 char(15)    NOT NULL,
MaxHours    int         DEFAULT 100 NOT NULL,
StartDate   DATE        NULL,
EndDate     DATE        NULL,
DepartmentName_FK1 char(30)   NULL,


Constraint  datecheck check (StartDate < EndDate),
Constraint ProjectIDPK   PRIMARY KEY(ProjectID),
Constraint DepartmentFK1 FOREIGN KEY (DepartmentName_FK1)
    references DEPARTMENT(DepartmentName)
-- ON UPDATE CASCADE 
-- ON DELETE no ACTION 
);

CREATE TABLE Assignment(
ProjectID       Number      NOT NULL,
EmployeeNumber  Number      NOT NULL,
HoursWorked     Number      NULL,
DepartmentName_FK2 char(30)   NULL,

Constraint ProjectIDEmpNumPK PRIMARY KEY(ProjectID, EmployeeNumber),
constraint ProjectIDEmpNumFK FOREIGN KEY(DepartmentName_FK2)
    references Department(DepartmentName)
--ON DELETE CASCADE 
);
```

If anyone notices anything wrong with these table declarations in relation to the questions i posted you can let me know? also, i just need to figure out how to syntactically write cascade updates and deletions.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to create a column for that FK on your EMPLOYEE table 
 **Your table should look like this** :

```
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE (
EmployeeNumber  int         NOT NULL,
FirstName       char(25)    NOT NULL,
LastName        char(25)    NOT NULL,
Department      char(35)    DEFAULT 'Human Resources' NOT NULL,
Phone           char(12)    NULL,
Email           char(30)    NOT NULL,
DepartmentName_FK char(35) NOT NULL,
Constraint EmployeePK   PRIMARY KEY(EmployeeNumber),
Constraint EmployeeAK1 UNIQUE(Email),
Constraint DepartmentFK FOREIGN KEY (DepartmentName_FK)
    references DEPARTMENT(DepartmentName));
```

Try it now !

Take a look at this article i wrote about [constraints](http://www.aodba.com/en/blog/2014/12/11/17-sql-constraints-mysql/) , it will help you understand better !

Comment: that got rid of one! :D i shall try doing that on the other, I guess every time i make a foreign key constraint i have to declare it first at the top?

Comment: i mean you need to have column that will represent each other !! on both tables!!

Comment: im still getting the error:
Constraint EmployeePK PRIMARY KEY(EmployeeNumber),
                                  *
ERROR at line 9: 
ORA-00904: "EMPLOYEENUMBER": invalid identifier 

how do I make the table Project have access to EmployeeNumber ?

Comment: I don't understand your question ?

Comment: You project table can not have a primary key represented by it's FK ! You will have to rethink this one !

Comment: I guess what i should ask is how to properly answer questions 7.6 and 7.7 @_@ T_T

Comment: actually i figured out the third table

Comment: .. and the fourth... i now understand how to make foreign and primary keys .. i just need to figure out how to cascade updates and deletions

Answer (score 0):

actually you have too many issues in your lines. for example in employee your foreign key is on column `DepartmentName` while in employee table you don't have that column you have `Department`

And this:

```
  Constraint  datecheck check (Assignment.StartDate < Assignment.EndDate),
```

In assignment table, I think you meant to put it in Project table, as in assignment there is no start and end date

I created a working [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/07861) for you to check.

Comment: interesting, i was kinda wondering the same thing when i was reading 7.8 (I added the question) it asked me to modify assignment table to have the datecheck constraint... why would it do that?

Comment: who asked you? I didn't understand... If you want to add that constraint to assignment table, you have to add the columns to that table. Constraints works on existing columns on the parent table, and the table you're creating. So let's say you are creating a foreign key in table Y on column Z to reference column A in table X. Table Y should have a column called Z and table X should have a column called A that is primary key.

Comment: wait a minute, i think the problem was i wrote assignment.startdate instead of project.startdate, inside of the assignment table constraint

Comment: @Mr.AwesomeSauce Yeah I already saw that, but that wouldn't mean anything in assignment table. Why would you want to test assignment start date/end date inside assignment table. You want this constraint when adding a project to the projects table

Comment: true.. it didnt work that way when i ran it the final time.. im just wondering why it asked me to do it that way in the question?

_7.7 Write a CREATE TABLE statement for the ASSIGNMENT table. Cascade only deletions from
PROJECT to ASSIGNMENT; do not cascade either deletions or updates from EMPLOYEE to 
ASSIGNMENT.

7.8 Modify your answer to Review Question 7.7 to include the constraint that StartDate
 be prior to EndDate._

?